# Display holiday on datepicker

Tags: jquery

I am using datepicker. I want to display list of indian holiday on calender. 
I am using below script. Calender working fine. Only i need to display holiday.

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker-dep').datepicker({numberOfMonths: 2, showCurrentAtPos: 0,minDate: 0});

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify all Indian holidays and mark them on datepicker.
Check out the following thread on how to do that,

[Mark selected days in jQuery UI datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001896/mark-selected-days-in-jquery-ui-datepicker)

also the api about this,

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add the Indian holidays here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var datesArray=['7/1/2012','7/4/2012']
$(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
         inline: true,
         beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var theday = (date.getMonth()+1) +'/'+ 
                        date.getDate()+ '/' + 
                        date.getFullYear();
                return [true,$.inArray(theday, datesArray) >=0?"specialDate":''];
            }
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.specialDate { background-color: #6F0 !important; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I solved this by using below code. I need to mention all holiday day which i want to display

```
<script>

    var unavailableDates = ["16-10-2013", "4-11-2013", "25-12-2013"];

   function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
        return [true, ""];
    } else {
        return [false, "", "Holiday"];
    }
}

$(function() {
    $("#datepicker-dep").datepicker({numberOfMonths: 2, showCurrentAtPos: 0,minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        beforeShowDay: unavailable
    });

      $("#datepicker-return").datepicker({numberOfMonths: 2, showCurrentAtPos: 0,minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        beforeShowDay: unavailable
    });

})


   </script>
```